# Why Xtext doesn't recognize JavaFX properties?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, javafx, xtext

I started using JavaFX recently. Unfortunately I've been unable to use auto-complete in my css editor with XText.

My project was created using maven so I added JavaFX SDK to the class path.

I'm working on eclipse Luna 4.4 editing the css files with e(fx)clipse Css Editor.

How can I have Xtext working correctly while editing Css files in eclipse?

Comment: Have you tried creating a plain project using the wizards and does the autocomplete work there?
It's hard to comment why this is not working with more details. I suggest to use the user support forum of the project at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/ and provide screenshots of your project explorer.

Comment: @tomsontom Actually something strange happened. When I created an FX project as you suggested both the new project and the old one (the one created with maven) started to work. So I'm guessing is some kind of bug...

Comment: Might be interesting if you can reproduce the Problem in a new workspace

Comment: @tomsontom I will try to replicate it. Where should I post the bug if I can?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of being unable to get auto-complete with my JavaFX CSS. My fix was add the JavaFX SDK to the library list. To do that:

1. Go to Project | Properties
2. Select Java Build Path in the tree
3. Click on the Libraries tab
4. Click the Add Library... button
5. Choose JavaFX SDK
6. Click Next then Finish
7. Click Apply
8. Click OK

CSS editing worked after those steps.